# Why I'm not getting any up votes for my answers recently?

Tags: support, voting, answers, upvotes

I have experienced a strange thing that I have got zero votes for my last 13 answers in Stackoverflow.This is the first time it's happening for me. I have 1340 Reputation in SO and I don't think my answers are that much bad. What are the other factors influencing up votes except quality ? Or SO locked my account for getting up votes or something ?

[image]

Comment: Your [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23590270/464709) literally is `You can use Rewirite [sic] Rules for IIS7 [reference link]`. That's a link-only answer and is not very useful, if you provide more information about the specific rewrite rule(s) to use it may attract more votes.

Comment: You are on the right tack for the "Unsung Hero" badge :). you just need to ask these new users to accept you answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going through your last 13 answers, I see most of them are questions asked by low reputation users who might not yet know how upvoting works, the questions have a low view count so few people noticed your answer at all, and one of the questions is a few years old.

So either you've been unlucky with the questions not attracting views, or the questions are just not interesting enough to the community to view them.